# A global struct pointer is used, but it does not take input. In C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

The input lines are marked beside.
Here,
*ptr is a global struct pointer.
In the main function, the get_data() function is called but it does not take any input rather the program terminates.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    struct detail
    {
        int present, absent, credit, left_weeks;
    };

    struct detail *ptr;             // global

    void get_data()
    {
        printf("\nYou have opted for Entering the data \n");
        printf("\nEnter the number of presents - ");
        scanf("%d",&ptr->present);                                       // First input

        printf("\nEnter the number of absents - ");
        scanf("%d",&ptr->absent);                                        // Second input

        printf("\nEnter the subject credit - ");
        scanf("%d",&ptr->credit);                                        // Third input

        printf("\nEnter the number of weeks left - ");
        scanf("%d",&ptr->left_weeks);                                    // Fourth input
    }

    int main()
    {
        get_data();
    }
```

I have checked in visual studio code and also an online compiler.
Could anyone help.

Comment: ptr is a null pointer. So the program has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`ptr` points nowhere. And there is no variable of type `struct detail` in this code.

You probably want this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct detail
{
    int present, absent, credit, left_weeks;
};

struct detail foo;         // << the actual variable you forgot
struct detail *ptr = &foo;             // globalptr points to foo
...
```

and all your `scanf`s are wrong, the `%d` specifier wants a *pointer* to int but you provide an `int`.

You want this:

```
scanf("%d", &ptr->present);
            ^you forgot this
```

That being said, your approach is overly complicated, you probably just want this:

```
scanf("%d", &foo.present);
```

and remove the global `ptr` pointer alltogether.

Answer (score 0):

already answered but I want to elaborate.

```
struct detail *ptr;
```

creates a pointer whose job is to point at an instance of detail. *but* you have not told it which one to point at (Imagine you had several instances of details in you program). In fact you dont have any instances of detail yet.

So you have to create an instance of detail

On the stack and set ptr to point at it

```
 int main (..){
   ...
   struct detail d; 
   ptr = &d;
```

On the heap

```
 int main (..){
   ...
   struct detail *d = malloc(sizeof(struct detail));
   ptr = d;  // d is a pointer already here
```

Or static global

```
  struct detail d;
  ....
  int main(..){

    ....
    ptr = &d;
```